# Test Null with JasperReports

Tags: java, if-statement, jasper-reports, ternary-operator

I Want to do something like this with *JasperReports*

```
 if (sum(columns) == NULL) 
    Write 0
ELSE
   Write Sum(Colones)
```

I can do it with other columns when the type is java.lang.String

```
($V{Adress}==null?"":$V{Adress}+"") //work and show blank ""
```

The problem is when the type is `java.math.BigDecimal`

```
($V{Sum_TAgraf}==null?:0,OO)  //here its not working i want to show me 0 not Null
```

Comment: [Ternary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Java)

Comment: `($V{Sum_TAgraf}==null?:0,OO)` - What is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't it be:

```
($V{Sum_TAgraf}==null?0,00:$V{Sum_TAgraf})
```

Comment: your expression not work but i found it its                                           $V{Sum_NBPChg}.equals(0.00)?0.00:$V{Sum_NBPChg}+0

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this:

```
 $V{Sum_NBPChg}.equals(0.00)?0.00:$V{Sum_NBPChg}+0
```